# numpyのフロート型でn乗の結果が正しい値にならない

Tags: python, numpy

`np.float32` でマイナスのフロートを2乗をすると正しい値を出力しません、なぜでしょうか？
Pythonでのfloat型では正しい値を出力します。

`a[0]` は`-1159.4025` です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`**` は`-` より演算子の優先順位が高いので `-100 ** 0.5` は `- (100 ** 0.5)` と解釈されています。
`(-100) ** 0.5` は 複素数 `0 + 10j` になり、`np.float32`では複素数を扱わず`nan`になります。

```
>>> -100 ** 0.5
-10.0
>>> (-100) ** 0.5
(6.123233995736766e-16+10j)

>>> np.float(-100.0) ** 0.5
(6.123233995736766e-16+10j)
>>> np.float_(-100.0) ** 0.5
nan
>>> np.float32(-100.0) ** 0.5
nan
>>> np.complex64(-100.0) ** 0.5
(6.123233995736767e-16+10.000000000000002j)
```

Answer (score 0):

**【回答】**
　Numpyのfloatも正しく動作しています。float32がいけないようです。

```
np.float(-1159.4025)**0.5
(2.084961175548369e-15+34.05j)

np.float32(-1159.4025)**0.5
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
```